# Override/replace /res/values/color.xml in android

Tags: java, android, xml, colors, android-theme

I am implementing theme change in my android app. In that i have declared 3 colors and implemented theme change using style.xml,theme.xml,attr.xml,color.xml.

But now i need to get the color value from webservice and change the color dynamically in color.xml

**My color.xml**

```
<color name="footer_active_orange">#c04a27</color>
<color name="footer_normal_orange">#ee672f</color>
```

In this i will get the color code i.e., **#c04a27 and #ee672f**
from webservice and i need to change this color code alone in xml file. For every attributes android generates a resource id in R.java while Build the project. So i cant able to modify/override/replace my color.xml. Provide me some solutions asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, that you can't change any resource xml  from code. 
Look into using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), it could be the solution for you.

Comment: So it is not possible to change xml files dynamically?

Comment: The resource xmls are normally stored inside the .apk file as pre-compiled semi-binary form, so you can't modify, override or replace with some plain text xml. Short answer: the resource xmls are hard-coded, and you can't modify them. The best, what you can do is get all the views, and modify the color. For example TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv); tv.setBackgroundColor(0xffee672f);

Comment: Thanks @Kari5 i have successfully implemented this using **SharedPreference**.